# Using xml and xsl to produce a xlsx file

Tags: xml, xslt, xlsx

I am trying to produce a xlsx report from a bunch of data. I have the mobile number, area code, and name of friends, and want to insert them into the xlsx file using xml and xsl.
I am having a hard time inserting the header of the data, and I can't seem to get the data on each column. Now, their just mashed together, with no seperator.

**XML file**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<jx:template xmlns:jx="http://apache.org/cocoon/templates/jx/1.0">
    <friends>
        <jx:forEach var="friendsDetail" items="${friendList}">
            <friend
                    Name="${friendsDetail.getName()}/"                                                
                    MobileNumber="${friendsDetail.getMobileNumber()}"
                    AreaCode="${friendsDetail.getAreaCode()}"
             />
        </jx:forEach>
    </friends>
</jx:template>
```

**XSL file**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="text" />
<xsl:strip-space elements="*" />
  <xsl:template match="friend">
  <xsl:value-of select="@Name" /><xsl:text/>
  <xsl:value-of select="@MobileNumber" /><xsl:text/>
  <xsl:value-of select="@AreaCode" /><xsl:text/>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

So basically, I want the data to come out in an xlsx file as follows:

```
       Column 1.  Column 2.       Column 3.

Row 1. Name       Mobilenumber    Areacode

Row 2. Peter      48785635        4817
```

Any tips will be greatly appreciated!

The output comes like this.

[image]

Comment: Your XSLT is actually produced a text output here, not xslx. That's not a problem because Excel can comma-delimited text files (for example). Are you actually trying to produce a CSV file here? (Or maybe a tab-delimited one?)

Comment: @TimC Yeah, I get an output file which is on the xlsx format, but I don´t get any seperator. I guess the tab-delimiter is the correct one). Please see the edit I made on the question (the output file).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want a tab-delimited file to import into Excel, you could start of by defining a parameter to hold the character for the delimited

```
<xsl:param name="separator" select="'&#x9;'" />
```

You could use a `xsl:variable` but a param could be overridden by the calling application, allowing you to easily swap to a comma.

You can then easily output the separator in your template

```
<xsl:value-of select="@Name" />
<xsl:value-of select="$separator" />
```

Try this XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="text" />

<xsl:param name="separator" select="'&#x9;'" />

<xsl:strip-space elements="*" />

<xsl:template match="friends">
  <xsl:text>Name</xsl:text>
  <xsl:value-of select="$separator" />
  <xsl:text>Mobile Number</xsl:text>
  <xsl:value-of select="$separator" />
  <xsl:text>Area Code</xsl:text>
  <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
  <xsl:apply-templates select="friend" />
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="friend">
  <xsl:value-of select="@Name" />
  <xsl:value-of select="$separator" />
  <xsl:value-of select="@MobileNumber" />
  <xsl:value-of select="$separator" />
  <xsl:value-of select="@AreaCode" />
  <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: is there btw a way to force the output to come to row 1 in the excel file? It keeps on coming on row 2, which would make my functions that read, fail.

Comment: If you don't want the header row, just remove the template that matches "friends"

Comment: Yes, I understand that, but the headers appear on row 2. Please see the edited question.

Comment: The XSLT itself shouldn't produce an empty line at the start; see http://xsltransform.net/a9GiwZ so maybe the problem is elsewhere. For example, how are you actually invoking the XSLT and saving the output?